# How to get the mails from outlook based on categorized

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get all mails from outlook using Graphapi,
for below code shows only unread mails will get,

but, here I need to get it category, like below [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/outlookcategory?view=graph-rest-1.0)

```
String filterCondition = "isRead eq false";
if (isArchiveFlow) {
    filterCondition = isInfoMailBox ? "" :"isRead eq true";
}
        
return _appClient.users(o365Mailbox)
        .mailFolders("inbox")
        .messages()
        .buildRequest()                
        .select("from,isRead,receivedDateTime,sentDateTime,subject,body,bodyPreview,flag,toRecipients,ccRecipients,bccRecipients,sender,hasAttachments")
        .filter(filterCondition)              
        .top(1000)//Default is 10 and $top accepts a minimum value of 1 and a maximum value of 999 (inclusive).
        .orderBy("receivedDateTime ASC")//ASC - For older emails and DESC - For new emails
        .get();
```

instead of using `isRead` conditions I need to get mails based on category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`categories` property is a collection, so you need to use `any`

```
String filterCondition = "categories/any(c:c eq 'Green')";
```

If some messages have two categories, let's say `Green` and `Red` and you want to get messages with both categories then `filterCondition` will be

```
String filterCondition = "categories/any(c:c eq 'Green') and categories/any(c:c eq 'Red')";
```

If want to get messages with either `Green` or `Red`

```
String filterCondition = "categories/any(c:c eq 'Green') or categories/any(c:c eq 'Red')";
```

Comment: Thank you @user2230153, how can I make categories once after the read the mail by email gate way .. and also if there is no categories mentioned, then I will get all mails ?

Comment: please help how can add Category in com.microsoft.graph.models.Message,                       Message newMessage = new Message();
   newMessage.isRead = true;
   newMessage.importance = Importance.LOW;
   newMessage.categories = not sure how to add it.   
   if(shouldFlag) {
    newMessage.flag =  message.flag;
    newMessage.flag.flagStatus = FollowupFlagStatus.FLAGGED;
   }
   
   _appClient.users(o365Mailbox)
       .messages(message.id)
       .buildRequest()
     .patch(newMessage);
 }

Comment: How can get email by NO category code instead of UNREAD?